# jquery 1.5 .live issue with FF & IE9

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jquery function that utilize the .live function.

It applies to newly added element that is not there when $(document).ready

The function works in Chrome but not FF or IE.

The page is loading 1.5min

```
<script>
        $("#345").live("keypress", function(){
                if (event.which == '13') {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $('#123').focus();
                }

});


$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#123').focus();
});


</script>
```

Edit: Also tried putting the .live codes in the .ready function. Same result

Comment: are these your real ids? Id's cannot start with numerals. Not sure if this is the issue though. Also, why do you use escaping?

Comment: Why do you escape the double quotes? That does not seem to be right...

Comment: Yes. They are real ids. Let me try changing it. Because other functions works with the same id.

Comment: `$(\"#345\").live(\"keypress\", function(event){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use numeric IDs, it's good practice to treat them as you would any identifiers in most programming languages.

You also left out the `event` parameter from your function definition in the first line:

```
$("#345").live("keypress", function(event){
    if (event.which == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#123').focus();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#123').focus();
});
```

It's also good practice not to wrap your jQuery in PHP strings, either close the PHP tag before and reopen it after, or restructure your code to prevent hard to debug quote issues. It would also do proper syntax highlighting in some text editors, making your job easier.

Comment: Thanks, this was it. But I also tried adding the event before. The problem was I didn't F5 it.